# WCF store data for current context

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, wcf, azure

I have an application existing of a website, local WPF client and a WCF service for communication with the client. These applications are currently being installed once per customer. I'd like to migrate my WCF-Service to azure and therefore accept calls from different customers. The only thing that actually changes is the db-connection string.

[image]

My business logic builds on EF. EF always gets the connection string from a static method which reads it out of the config-file. (currently)

So my question is: Where can I store the db-connection-string for the current caller? I know there is OperationContext, but I need something less specific so the library can be used for all type of apps i have. I thought of storing the caller in Thread.Principal but I'm not sure this is the right approach.

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: you want an service in the cloud that targets some local databases per client?

Comment: No, sorry for the unprecise explanation. Database, service and website are in the cloud, on the client is the WPF-App and a copy of the database which synchronizes over the WCF service...

Comment: but why do you have to change the connection based on the caller?

Comment: Currently the infrastructure is deployed for each customer. Say we have 4 customers means 4 databases, 4 websites 4 WCF-services, and maybe 8 WPF clients (2 per customer). The goal is to only use 1 WCF Service for all 4 customers. For that service I need to decide which customer is calling meaning what database to address.